# Why so many writers for "Land of the Lost"?

Tags: screenwriter, crew, land-of-the-lost-1974

The crew of the [*Land of the Lost* (1974-1976)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_of_the_Lost_(1974_TV_series)) had a large number of writers:

[image: Land of the Lost writers]

In fact, there were almost as many writers as all the other crew members combined. Is this normal? Why would the series have so many different writers?

Comment: Dammit, now I'm going to have that theme song in my ear all day.....

Comment: Perhaps some got lost.

Answer (score 7):

This is/was entirely normal.

It's likely that the writers were only responsible for writing perhaps a single episode or two...or perhaps just consulted on script/story re-writes.

See the same list on [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071005/fullcredits?ref_=tt_ql_1)

[image]

Individual writers would often pitch or be contracted for a single episode. If you are a SF reader you'll recognise many of the names on the list of contributors.

...the same was true of [*Star Trek-TOS*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060028/fullcredits?ref_=tt_ql_1)

Recall that these episodes are usually written for a weekly broadcast and were pushed out at a remarkable rate and number. It just makes sense that you field the largest "team" possible.

Single episode writers wouldn't have been "on-staff"...they would have been contracted. There would have been a *core* of staff writers who would take the submitted scripts and fit them into the show format.

Comment: Ok, but what is the rationale? Why not just simplify things by having a small number of writers that focus on the show?

Comment: Because you take ideas from anywhere and fit them into the show format. Added more to the answer.

Comment: DC Fontana and Walter Koenig were both involved with Star Trek, in fact.  Probably more, but I recognize those 2 right off the bat.  Koenig wrote and played Checkov, of course.

Comment: @JohnnyBones David Gerrold wrote The Trouble with Tribbles. Norman Spinrad: The Doomsday Machine. Larry Niven wrote an episode of the animated Star Trek series... and that's just off the top of my head.

Comment: Also Sturgeon was a noted sci-fi writer too, and he held the rights to a character he created for an episode for example that caused an issue later on when ST: Ent was being written. Iirc he contributed to at least two stories, and was known as a bit of a slow writer